# Postgresql tuple constraints about NOT NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, tuples, constraints

I am building a database in POSTGRESQL, and I would like to create NOT NULL constraints for my columns, where one and only one column would be NOT NULL.

I have two columns in my table, site_id and buffer_result_id. Only one of these columns will have values.

```sql
alter table dt.analysis_result
add constraint ar_check check (site_id NOT NULL OR buffer_result_id NOT NULL);
```

The above code is just some pseudo-code to show my idea. How can I achieve this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `XOR` expressed as:

```
alter table dt.analysis_result
add constraint ar_check check (
 (site_id IS NOT NULL OR buffer_result_id IS NOT NULL) 
  AND NOT(site_id IS NOT NULL AND buffer_result_id IS NOT NULL) 
 );
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=00d35aaec8808db81d8503f3786404f0)**

More info: [Exclusive OR - Equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

---

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE analysis_result(site_id INT, buffer_result_id INT);

INSERT INTO analysis_result VALUES (NULL, NULL);
-- ERROR:  new row for relation "analysis_result" violates check constraint "ar_check"

INSERT INTO analysis_result VALUES (1, 2);
-- ERROR:  new row for relation "analysis_result" violates check constraint "ar_check"

INSERT INTO analysis_result VALUES (NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO analysis_result VALUES (1, NULL);

SELECT * FROM analysis_result
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can do this with a `check` constraint.  I think the simplest method is to count the number of `not null` values:

```
alter table dt.analysis_result add constraint ar_check
   check ( (site_id is not null)::int + (buffer_result_id is not null)::int = 1
         );
```

Comment: That is brilliant. May I ask the meaning of double colons(::)? Does it mean "expression AS type"? In this case, it means to express (site_id is not null) in the form of an integer?

Comment: @ruijiang . . . They are a convenient method to type conversion in Postgres.  You can also use `cast()`.